# How to test a React component with a service?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider a component with a service (REST or persistence, etc.), one way how to initialize the service is in the component constructor:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import MyRestService from '../service/MyRestService';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.service = new MyService('http://www.example.com');
    ...
```

Another way is to initialize it as a global constant:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import MyRestService from '../service/MyRestService';

const service = new MyService('http://www.example.com');

class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
```

Both ways are pretty static and don't follow me to initialize the service dynamically, so it is very difficult to test it.

In a test, I want to inject a mock service into the component and validate the calls to the service while simulate actions upon the component.

What's the best way to create a service for a React component to be testable with mocking?

Comment: In which way can your service be initialized? Does your component need to share the service response/results with any other component, or just use within itself and among its children?

Comment: @blaz The service should be encapsulated in the component, no sharing.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [testdouble.js](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js) to replace/mock dependencies.
You can do something like this in your test file

```
// replacing the dependency so that when the dependency is called
// in other file, it will get the mocked one instead.
const MyRestService = td.replace('../service/MyRestService');

// replace its behaviour
td.when(MyService('http://www.example.com')).thenReturn(something)

// validate that myservice has been called with particular argument
td.verify(MyService('http://www.example.com'))
```

Comment: My question was about how to create a service in the component, not how to create a mock of an object. If I create a mock as you proposed (or in any different way) - how do I inject it into the component??

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, you should provide 2 test suites: one solely for your service, as unit testing, and another for your component as integration testing. Validate service calls to your service would be tested in the unit tests, and component actions would be tested on integration tests.

For implementation, one way to make your service initiation more dynamic is to pass parameters for your service as props or state of your component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        initService();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prepProps, prepState) {
        if (prepProps.serviceParams !== this.props.serviceParams) {
            initService();
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // stop whatever your service is doing here
        delete this.service;
    }

    initService() {
        if (!!this.props.serviceParams) {
            if (!!this.service) {
                // stop your current service
            }
            this.service = new MyService(this.props.serviceParams);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe even to set the service from outside would be best: `this.service = props.service`, thanks for the idea!